# Fullscreen iPad UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have an iPad app which displays a `UIImagePicker` through a `UIPopoverController`.
I would like to make the popovercontroller fullscreen (or at least as big as possible).

I'm using the `presentPopoverFromRect` method with a new `CGRect` which I have set to various widths and heights with no result. The source of the imagepicker is `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`.

```
UIPopoverController* popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:photoPicker];
popoverController.delegate = self;
popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2500, 2500) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Can I even make this fullscreen? What about sourcetype `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set popover size you can override `-contentSizeForViewInPopover` in viewcontroller which is 
placed in popovercontroller.

`presentPopoverFromRect` is used for defining frame from which popover will be opened, not for setting it's size.

Comment: Then I would need to extend UIImagePickerController and add the -contentSizeForViewInPopover method there? Is this the only way to set it's size?

Comment: `UIImagePickerController` inherits from `UIViewController` so it has already implemented `-contentSizeForViewInPopover`. Just use `popoverController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(w,h);` before loading into popover controller

Answer (score 1):

I just verified that this code works on an iPad 1 and iPad 4 (meaning it is supported in iOS 5.1.1 - 6.1.2)

```
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:yourVC];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 1024)];

    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectZero
                                       inView:appDelegate.splitViewController.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                     animated:YES];
```

You should note that it's difficult to dismiss the popover since it will "fill the screen" in portrait or landscape.  I do have these methods in my appDelegate.splitViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods {

    NSLog(@"MG - shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers {

    NSLog(@"MG - automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers");
    return YES;
}
```

Just unhide/hide a button in a corner of yourVC to dismiss with this:

```
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

It should also be noted that "popover" is a strong property, or you will get a deallocated message when it tries to present.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want a ModalViewController instead? This one has 4 different presentationstyles (one of them fullscreen)

A good example is the prototype written in this question: [presentModalViewController fullscreenmode issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607271/presentmodalviewcontroller-fullscreenmode-issue)
(it's in the //---*EDIT*---//)

Check it out if it's something for you.

Comment: This doesn't work. That's how I tried it at first until I got an exception saying:
'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'